# Problemas com dados de entrada na Rede neural com scikit learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, redes-neurais

Gostaria de criar uma rede neural que retorna 1 (um) para um caso específico e 0 (zero) para todos os outros.

A ideia seria:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MaxAbsScaler
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

# transforma o dado (3000 valores) em um dataframe

traco = pd.read_fwf('2_traco48.txt', header=None)

# recorta o dado em janelas com 100 valores

for i in range(0,2901):
    janela[i] = traco[i:i+100]
    print janela[i]

# lista com todas as janelas

janelas [janela0, janela1, janela2, ... janela 2900, janela2901]

# saida desejada (caso hipotetico, a ultima saida sera 1 e as outras seriam 0)

saida = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ... 0, 0, 0, 1]

# treinando

ann =  MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', hidden_layer_sizes=(10, 10), activation='logistic', alpha=1e-5,)
print(ann.fit(janelas, saida))
```

Ainda não fiz as partes de "recortar" as janelas nem especificar a lista com a posição do 1 e dos zeros, além de normalizar os dados para ficarem entre 1 e -1.

Testando um exemplo mais simples, com apenas 4 "janelas" com 100 valores de entrada cada janela, para ver como estaria rodando, me deparei com um problema:

```
data0 = pd.read_fwf('data0.txt', index=False)
data1 = pd.read_fwf('data1.txt', index=False)
data2 = pd.read_fwf('data2.txt', index=False)
data3 = pd.read_fwf('data3.txt', index=False)

dado_treino = [data0, data1, data2, data3]
treino_superv = [0, 0, 0, 1]

print(ann.fit(dado_treino, treino_superv))
```

Transformei os arquivos 'data[i].txt' de 2D para 1D, mas não está dando certo...

```
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 99 to array axis with dimension 1
```

Acredito que o erro esteja na conversão do dado de 2D para 1D com o pandas, mas pode ser algo na rede, ou algo conceitualmente errado.

Comment: Vc pode postar a msg completa de erro? Com a linha exata onde está acontecendo fica mais fácil saber qual o problema :)

Comment: Victor Capone, o erro é "ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 99 to array axis with dimension 1". A questão é que meus dados deveriam ser um array de uma linha, isso que não estou conseguindo fazer.

Comment: Seria interessante se você postasse mensagem de erro. Mas pelo que entendi você esta utilizando 4 pandas.DataFrames dentro de uma array. Tipo você deve olhar cada DF desses e ver sem tem o mesmo tamanho. como ta o shape. tipo o problem esta no preprocessamento .